# SpringBoot - Java AWS SDK 2 DynamoDB Enhanced Client and devtools problem

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Spring Boot 2.17 and java sdk and dynamodb-enhanced '2.13.8'.

I am calling with the enhanced client an item like this:

```
public Product readProductById(String id) {
    Key key = Key.builder()
            .partitionValue(id)
            .build();
    Product product =  productTable.getItem(key);
    return product;
}
```

it leads when called to this error:

```
class de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product cannot be cast to class de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product (de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @19e19c7e)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product cannot be cast to class de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product (de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; de.xxx.productsapi.db.Product is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @19e19c7e)
```

Switching the `livereload to enabled: false` did not help but completly removing the devtools worked. But this a not statisfying solution since I want to use the devtools.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring Boot DevTools restart functionality is implemented using two classloaders. The project is loaded by the restart classloader and the libraries are loaded by the base classloader.

Use the file `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties` to move DynamoDB jars into the `RestartClassloader`:

```
restart.include.dynamodb=/dynamodb-[\\w\\d-\.]+\.jar
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload