# AWS JAVA dynamoDB enhanced client putItem class cast exception

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

When I used enhanced client to put but it throws class cast exception.

```
DynamoDbTable<Tableclass> recordTable = enhanceClient.table(tableName, Tableclass.class);

Tableclass tableclass = new Tableclass();
tableclass.setid(1);
tableclass.setname("myname");
recordTable.putItem(tableclass);
```

It gives me error
java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.db.dynamo.Tableclass cannot be cast to com.db.dynamo.Tableclass

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with aws sdk version 2.16.45. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: In my case, this post regarding spring devtools solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350067/1612280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me [SpringBoot - Java AWS SDK 2 DynamoDB Enhanced Client and devtools problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556638/springboot-java-aws-sdk-2-dynamodb-enhanced-client-and-devtools-problem/64350067#64350067)

So basically the issue was with spring dev tools and its class loader(2 in number), so you can either remove it or move dynamo to the same class loader.